# NSTimer does not invalidate

Tags: ios, timer, objective-c-blocks, dispatch-async

I have a problem invalidating my timer.

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;`

Inside my block on success, I am allocating and setting my timer on main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[Config refreshInterval].integerValue target:self selector:@selector(methodThatHasABlockCalledMentionedAbove) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
});
```

At my `textFieldDidBeginEditing` I am invalidating my timer like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.timer invalidate];
        self.timer = nil;
 });
```

My method still gets executed on timer. What's the catch?

Comment: check if self.timer isn't nil when you call dispatch async... `assert(self.timer)`

Comment: I've checked. It's not nil

Comment: are you then maybe setting several  timer objects without invalidating the old one?

Comment: before you do  `self.timer = .....` , call `[self.timer invalidate];`

Comment: @Daij-Djan I believe your comment is the correct answer.  I was just about to suggest that as an answer.

Comment: That was the problem. I've just invalidated and set to nil my timer before scheduling on my main thread and now it's ok. Thank you

Comment: @Flipper made it an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are setting several timer objects without invalidating the old ones first?!

releasing a timer objects thats already scheduled will not invalidate the timer, so:

before you do `self.timer = ....` , call `[self.timer invalidate];`